# Counting results in an JavaScript array

Tags: javascript

How do you count results within an array?

I am counting the occurrences of a pattern in an array and could like it to return as

```
[0, 0, 0]
```

For example with each element of the array representing a search result.

This is what I've done so far... but it seems to only return [object object]...

```
pages=[
"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry."
, 
"It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout", 
"There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable." 
]
pattern = prompt("Enter a search string")

    var count = {};

    for(i=0; i<pages.length; i++)
    {
         for(j=0; j<pattern.length; j++)
         {
               if((pages[i].toLowerCase()
                           .indexOf(pattern.toLowerCase()
                                           .charAt([j])))<0)
               {
                  count[i]++;
               }
         }
    }

    alert(count);
```

Comment: Well, that's because it is an object. Dir it to the console to view its contents: `console.dir( count );`

Comment: Why are you iterating over each character or the search string? Don't you just want to search for the entire pattern?

Comment: Yes I do and I thought this solution would work best!

Comment: Is there any way I can improve it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. Could you update your question with an example (pages + search string + expected result)?

Comment: I'm trying to return a true value if all the individual characters of pattern appear in string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var count, allCounts = [];

for(i=0; i<pages.length; i++)
{
     count = 0;
     for(j=0; j<pattern.length; j++)
     {
           if((pages[i].toLowerCase()
                       .indexOf(pattern.toLowerCase()
                                       .charAt([j])))<0)
           {
              count++;
           }
     }
     allCounts.push(count);
}
alert('[' + allCounts.join(', ') + ']');
```

I suggest that you .toLowerCase your pattern once before the start of any of the loops, that would avoid doing the toLowerCase operation i * j times.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to move the alert(count) up 2 lines to be like this:

```
var count = {};

           for(i=0;i<pages.length;i++)
           {
               for(j=0;j<pattern.length;j++)
                   {
                       if((pages[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(pattern.toLowerCase().charAt([j])))<0)
                       {
                           count[i]++;
                       }
                   }
            alert(count[i]); // but note that it will appear multiple times
           }
```

Comment: Alerting within a loop - sounds like fun. Console please.